# Matching a character which occurs single

Tags: java, regex

I have two strings like this: `"A == B", "C = D"`. I want to find out whether a string contains assignment operator `=` or equal to `==` operator. For example `"C=D"` should returns true and `"C=D=D"` should returns true as well. But `"A==B"` should returns false. I tried `"[^=][=][^=]"` but it is returning false for both strings.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^=][=][^=]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("A=B");

System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

This is returning `false` but I want to get `true`.

Comment: why not `String.contains ("==")`

Comment: I want to determine single `"="` caharacters.

Comment: Do `!myString.contains("==")` instead.

Comment: String could be like this: `"A+B"`

Comment: What should the result be for that example?

Comment: Lets try to more spesific. If my string contains =, but it is not part of a condition operator like ==, this should be an invalid string. That what I trying to achieve.

Comment: For "A=B", your regex expression and example can return "true", while "A = B" return "false". Notice the white space in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, `Matcher.match()` will try to match the whole string. To just find a sub-string in between, you should use `Matcher.find()` instead.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^=][=][^=]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("A=B");

System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

This will return `true` for any string with single `'='` only. And will return `false` for string containing `'=='`.

Comment: @Lokesh, Are you sure you know what OP wants? He wants A=B ==> true while A==B ==> false.

Comment: Basically OP want to check whether a string contain assignment operator or equal to operator. If it contain assignment operator it should return true else if it contain equal to operator it should return false.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew my regex was correct. The answer is: use `find` instead of `matches`.

Comment: @Joseph K., just find out that "A==B=C" will return true. Is it the result you want also?

Comment: Yeap. If any single "=" occurs it should return true.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `!myString.contains("==")` which will return `true` if `myString` does not have `==`. If you want to guarantee at least one `=` then do

```
myString.contains("=") && !myString.contains("==")
```

Comment: My explanation was insufficient I think. If it is contains a `=` character individual it is an invalid string. Your code does not work for this: `A==B && A=B`. This should be invalid as well.

Comment: @JosephK. Both expressions in my answer will evaluate to `false` for this example because it contains `==`. I am now confused because your comment here seems the opposite of your original question. What do you mean by "If it is contains a = character individual it is an invalid string"? This seems to contradict "For example "C=D" should returns true" from your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding regular expression is `"[^=]+=[^=]+"`, assuming you allow any length and whitespaces before and after the = sign.

```
jshell> "A=B".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$6 ==> true

jshell> "Ad=Bd".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$7 ==> true

jshell> "Ad==Bd".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$8 ==> false

$jshell> "A==B".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$9 ==> false

jshell> "A cow = an animal".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$10 ==> true

jshell> "    =     ".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$11 ==> true

jshell> "=".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$12 ==> false

jshell> "A==B && A=B".matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
$13 ==> false
```

Though given the last example, I wonder if it is not better to use a tool like [XText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), which provide a better manner at parsing expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Trying buiding the Regex again. Use https://regexr.com to solve it. You pattern matches only "A=B" "C=D" "=A=B" and changing it to "[^=][=][^=][=][^=]" will make it recognize "A=B=C" and "A=F=R" or "=A=B=C". Thus check your Regex.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Z0W.png)

Comment: I tried already. Strangely It is working on regexr but not on java.

Comment: Why need a regex if this problem can be easily solved by string functions ?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: your string function?

Comment: @JosephK. sorry typo mistake it's by. See Code-Apprentice answer

Comment: Regex = [A-Za-z](={1}[A-Za-z])+ Try this one.