# Regular Expression in java for escape special character (*) if it contains more than one continuously

Tags: java

Example:

```
Input 1 - Some Text * Some Text (or) Some * Text * Some Text ------->Output - True
Input 2 - Some Text ** Some Text  ------->Output - False
Input 3  -Some Text *** Some Text ------->Output - False
```

In above case, i need to escape if the String contains more then one star (*) continuously, so please suggest any example or any way to write regular expression.

Need Out Put like - Some Text * Some Text (or) Some * Text * Some Text

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: Have updated the post

Comment: Possible duplicated with [Matching a character which occurs single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681184/matching-a-character-which-occurs-single)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the occurrences of two or more stars with this

```
\\*{2,}
```

or the whole words they are in with this

```
\\w*\\*{2,}\\w*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to find all continuous `*`s:

```
\*{2,}
```

This regex matches a `*` (`\*`) at least 2 times, as many times as possible (`{2,}`).

Usage:

```
Pattern.compile("\\*{2,}").matcher(stringInput).matches()
```

If the above method returns true, that means your input should be escaped.

[Try it out here!](https://regex101.com/r/jzxNX2/2)

Comment: but i need to escape the input 2 and 3, if i replace, all 3 input will be validate by the regular expression, so

Comment: @NandhakumarAppavu what do you mean by "escape"? What do you expect the output to be for input 2 and 3?

Comment: I have updated the post, hope you will understand my expectation

Comment: @NandhakumarAppavu Edited.